# Straightening a tilted object in an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

[image: Solar panel]
In the following image of a solar panel the panel appears to be tilted how can i straighten it ? Can this be done using hough transform ?

Edit:
cv2.Houghlines gives an array of (rho,theta) values how do I find out the number of   votes got by each (rho,theta) value in the accumilator?

Comment: The Hough transform will return lines that are detected in the image. If you check the angles of those lines and see that, for e.g., most are -3 degrees and 87 degrees (horizontal and vertical lines), then you know that if you rotate by 3 degrees you should be able to correct it.

Comment: Make sure your camera is calibrated before you apply the hough transform. There seems to be a slight fisheye effect in the image at the extremeties

Comment: Did you try `cv2.minAreaRect(contour)`. It returns the angle of the rectangle which has the minimum area in the contour (in this case, it is the solar panels). Then you can use `cv2.warpAffine()` to straighten it.